Прогресс бар на Pillow
У меня в ТЗ стоит сделать прогресс бар:

Суть: прогресс бар должен проходить вокруг аватара пользователя, и значение начала и конца должно начинаться не четко под прямым углом, а от левой части уровня (число под аватаркой) и заканчиваться с правой части уровня. Если есть метод, как реализовать это на pillow библиотеке, скажите пожалуйста, как это реализовывается.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Почему именно pillow?

А чем не так pillow?

В pillow есть функция .arc(), которая как раз и рисует дугу:
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new("RGBA", (300, 300), "#cccccc"
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.arc((50, 50, 250, 250), start = 100, end = 80, fill = "#2f3136", width = 5)
img.save("arc.png")

Для угла start и end:

0 градусов - Восток (право)
90 градусов - Юг (низ)
180 градусов - Запад (лево)
270 градусов - Север (верх)

